# Loading Silverlight application with WCF-RIA into html div gives exception

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In my Silverlight application(SilverLight app1) i have a html page and onlick of button i want to load Silvelight application(SilverLight app2) into div present in html page,Silverlight xap file is present in ClientBin folder. In this, when Silverlight application contains silverlight controls then it loads properly, but when i add WCF - RIA services into my application, then onclick of button it throws exception "Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2104
Category: InitializeError
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings"
But when i run Silverlight application(SilverLight app2) it runs properly, but gives exception when trying to load into div in (SilverLight app1).
I serached for this exception, it says this occurs due to MIME type not set in IIS, but it is set in my case and i am using VS2010.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/javiervillarreal/archive/2008/06/14/silverlight-error-2104-could-not-download-the-silverlight-application-in-iis6.aspx